# Cannot position plotly legend outside plot borders

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plotly graph that uses the Dash library to manipulate the x-values on the plot for simple comparison. When x values, in this case countries, is greater than 1, the legend is properly positioned outside of the graph. However, when there is only one country on the plot, the legend covers half of the plot.

I have tried: setting the legend x attribute to 3, x anchor to right, and changing the graph margin to add padding. I haven't found a solution that works.

Below is the section of the code that updates the plotly fig.

```
   window_width = 1500
        fig = px.bar(data_frame=dfi5.loc[(value_country)], width=(window_width / 4) * len(value_country))
        fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True, title='')
        fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=True, title='Percent of Respondents')
        fig.update_layout(autosize=False, title_text='Favorite K-Drama by Country', title_x=.46, title_font_size=20,
                          legend_title_text='Drama Title', margin_r=1, legend_xanchor='right', legend_x=3, legend_itemsizing='constant')
```

[image: Plot with one country]

[image: Plot with greater than one country]

**Update:** I was able to find a workaround by reducing the legend font size, which reduces the area of the legend. I would be interested to learn if there is a way to explicitly set the location of the legend. The issue seems to occur when the legend area is wider than the plot area.

Comment: I think the legend is _a part of the figure_, it cannot be outside it. Maybe the problem is with the width? Can you fix the figure width to the whole page? It looks like the width is wrong and therefore whole image became too narrow

Comment: Because I am adding x values through a multi-select, sometimes there will be one x value and sometimes there will be several. If I set the width of the figure to the entire page when there is one x value, I get one extremely fat bar. But yes, the legend will be properly set. I am looking for a solution for when the width is small, but the legend is wide.

Comment: could you separate the bar width (`width=(window_width / 4) * len(value_country)` in your code I believe) from the figure width and use two variables? In this case, when there is one x value, you can clamp the bar width to a maximum value and let the figure width be large.

Comment: @elgordorafiki You are correct! This issue was completely a width setting issue.

Comment: cool, happy to have helped.